# Am I going the right way to make login system secure with this simple password salting?

Tags: php, salt

I have two fields in `login` table

- password
- salt

And I have this little function to generate salt

```
function random_salt($h_algo="sha512"){
        $salt1=uniqid(rand(),TRUE);
        $salt2=date("YmdHis").microtime(true);
        if(function_exists('dechex')){
            $salt2=dechex($salt2);
        }
        $salt3=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $salt=$salt1.$salt2.$salt3; 

        if(function_exists('hash')){
            $hash=(in_array($h_algo,hash_algos()))?$h_algo:"sha512";
            $randomsalt=hash($hash,md5($salt)); //returns 128 character long hash if sha512 algorithm is used.
        }else{
            $randomsalt=sha1(md5($salt)); //returns 40 characters long hash
        }

        return $randomsalt;
    }
```

Now to create user password  I have following

```
$userinput=$_POST["password"] //don't bother about escaping, i have done it in my real project.
$static_salt="THIS-3434-95456-IS-RANDOM-27883478274-SALT"; //some static hard to predict secret salt.
$salt=random_salt(); //generates 128 character long hash.
$password =sha1($salt.$userinput.$static_salt);
```

`$salt` is saved in `salt` field of database and `$password` is saved in `password` field.

My problem, In function `random_salt()`, I m having this FEELING that I'm just making things complicated while this may not generate secure salt as it should. Can someone throw me a light whether I m going in a right direction?

P.S. I do have an idea about `crypt` functions and like such. Just want to know is my code okay?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obviously a security problem:

```
uniqid(rand(),TRUE);
```

How did you set the seed for rand().? Where is you entropy pool?
As long as you can't answer the salt has to be considered predictable. Remember: security doesn't come from code obscurity. 


If you choose a good PRNG all the other salts (e.g. server name, static long salt, time etc..) become irrilevant.

Answer (score 2):

You really should take a look at this question/answer ::
[How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php)

In short, don't roll your own if you don't need to.